# Meaning of asterisk in these examples

Tags: c

what is the meaning of the asterisk after a variable, for example here in the function _tempnam ? :

`_CRTIMP char* __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW    _tempnam (const char*, const char*);`

I always see this in function arguments.

Comment: Are you aware of the concept of pointers containing the address of variables of an existing type? If not the answers will probably boil down to "read that up". If yes I do not really understand what your question is.

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-pointers

Comment: @jcc3dx There is no variable in the presented code.

Comment: It's perhaps just a subtle linguistic point, but that is not an 'asterisk after a variable'.  It is an 'asterisk after a type'.  In a variable definition such as `char *a, *b;` you would say that the asterisk precedes the variable name.

Comment: This is most basic C knowledge. I'm not sure if this is the right place for asking this.

Comment: This is suspiciously similar to the very recent question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65598191/what-is-the-meaning-of-asterisk-parameter-on-stdcall-function

Comment: @EugeneSh. well, at least this is tagged with correct language...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_tempnam` is a function.
That function takes two parameters.

The first parameter is a pointer to a `char`.
Any `char` referenced by that pointer cannot be written-to (it is `const`).

The second parameter is a pointer to a `char`.
Any `char` referenced by that pointer cannot be written-to (it is `const`).

The return value of the function is a pointer to `char`.

The rest of the declaration suggests that the function is a C-Runtime-Implementation (CRTIMP), called using the C-calling convention, and does not throw any exceptions.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

These are `pointers`, a central C concept you should know about if you want to use this language. Some informations [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm).

Comment: Clear, short, true and still kind and via appropriate link helpful. I failed to think of an answer like this. Good work.